# FilePicker missing permission on Android 13 (Pixel 7)

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, filepicker

While I have no problem on past Android, on Android 13 (actually my Pixel 7) I get the following exception:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(read_external_storage_denied, User did not allow reading external storage, null, null))

While running my code as follows:

```dart
  final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                                type: Platform.isAndroid
                                    ? FileType.any
                                    : FileType.custom,
                                allowedExtensions: Platform.isAndroid
                                    ? null
                                    : ['bin', 'nano']);
```

I guess something has changed to the permission system.

I added the following permission to the `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` without success:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Any idea?

Comment: To pick a file and read it one does not need a single permission on Android. What is Flutter messing around that you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an issue for storage with Android 13 and you can read the discussion here https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/907

And the [last comment](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/907#issuecomment-1497635233) and [this Comment](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/907#issuecomment-1377587146) contains solution.

As SdkVersion 33 is for android 13 , changing it to 31 (android 12) .

so, may be it changing to 31 works as backward compatibility.

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

for permission

```
 var status = await Permission.storage.status;
debugPrint("storage permission " + status.toString());
if (await Permission.storage.isDenied) {

  debugPrint("sorage permission ===" + status.toString());
 
  await Permission.storage.request();
} else {
  debugPrint("permission storage " + status.toString());
 // do something with storage like file picker
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. For a quick fix, I downgraded to supporting Android 12 (changing `targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion` to `targetSdkVersion 31`)

Comment: Any solution if we want publish app to Google Play? As that requires targetting 33.

Answer (score 0):

The file_picker package version 4.5.1 has a known issue with requesting permission on Android 13. To fix this, you need to update the package version to 5.1.0 or later, as the developer has fixed this issue in the later versions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a quick solution then change your targetsdkversion 32

```
   defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.sslwireless.gmsb_offline"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32 // use this version for android 13
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```